# mod rewrite and static pages

Tags: mod-rewrite

is possible to exclude a url being parsed by mod rewrite?
my .htaccess has rewrite rules like

```
RewriteRule ^contact contact_us.php
```

and a couple more static pages.

currently my site don't have troubles cause uses http://domain.com/user.php?user=username
but now i need rewrite to:

```
http://domain.com/username
```

I've tried with:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ user.php?user=$1 [L]
```

but all my site stops working...

is possible to avoid parse my static pages like contact/feed/etc being treated like usernames?

edit to match david req:

this is my actual .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +Followsymlinks

RewriteRule ^contact contact_us.php [L]
RewriteRule ^terms terms_of_use.php [L]
RewriteRule ^register register.php [L]
RewriteRule ^login login.php [L]
RewriteRule ^logout logout.php [L]
RewriteRule ^posts/(.*)/(.*) viewupdates.php?username=$1&page=$2 
RewriteRule ^post(.*)/([0-9]*)$ viewupdate.php?title=$1&id=$2 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profile.php?username=$1 [L]
```

also i've enabled modrewrite log my first file:http://pastie.org/1044881

Comment: Thanks for the edit, the rewrite log will be extremely helpful. What I'd really like to see is the section of the rewrite log that corresponds to a request for `http://example.com/contact` (i.e. one that should be rewritten). One way to do that would be to delete the existing log, reload the server, visit the `contact` URL, then take the contents of the rewrite log file and post it on Pastie.

Comment: done! deleted log / reloaded server / new log same pastie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the rewrite rules for the static pages first, and add the `[L]` flag to them:

```
RewriteRule ^contact contact_us.php [L]
...
```

then *after* those, use your rewrite rule for the username:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ user.php?user=$1 [L]
```

(hopefully nobody has a username of `contact`).

**EDIT**: Based on the log output you posted (which I'm assuming corresponds to an *unsuccessful* attempt to access the `contact` page... right?), try changing the `contact` rewrite rule to either

```
RewriteRule ^contact$ contact_us.php [L]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^contact contact_us.php [L,NS]
```

That is, either add `$` to make the pattern match only the literal URL `contact`, or add the `NS` flag to keep it from applying to subrequests. According to the log output, what seems to have happened is that Apache rewrites `contact` to `contact_us.php` and then does an internal subrequest for that new URL. So far so good. The weird thing is that the `^contact` pattern again matches `contact_us.php`, "transforming" it to `contact_us.php`, i.e. the same thing, which Apache interprets as a signal that it should ignore the rule entirely. Now, I would *think* Apache would have the sense to ignore the rule only on the subrequest, but I'm not sure if it's ignoring the *entire* rewriting process and leaving the original URL, `/contact`, as is. If that's the case, making one of the changes I suggested should fix it.

**EDIT 2**: your rewrite log excerpt reminded me of something: I'd suggest making the rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ user.php?user=$1 [L]
```

since slashes shouldn't be occurring in any usernames. (Right?) Or you could do

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ user.php?user=$1 [L]
```

if usernames can only include word characters (letters, numbers, and underscore). Basically, make a regular expression that matches only any sequence of characters that could be a valid username, but doesn't match URLs of images or CSS/JS files.

Comment: thanks for the answer but all pages now are parsed like user.php
this code works RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$ user.php?user=$1 [L]
but isn't base of site.

any idea to tell rewriterule don't parse previously listed static pages?

Comment: So you're saying that when you access `example.com/contact`, the `RewriteRule ^contact ...` _doesn't_ seem to apply? If so, something must be wrong with the way your rules are configured. It would help if you edit your question to contain the _entire_ contents of the `.htaccess` file (or at least all the rewriting rules in it), along with its location in the filesystem, and the location of the document root. Also (maybe better yet), can you enable the [rewrite log](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog)?

Comment: Cool :-) You'll have to do the same with `terms`, `register`, `login`, and `logout` of course. Also, if my answer worked for you, it'd be nice if you mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

The `-f` and `-d` options to `RewriteCond` check if the current match is a file or directory on disk.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ....
```