# .htaccess rewrite without it affecting relative image/css/js URLs?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, relative-url

I need some simple help with my htaccess file, thank you in advance.

I have a number website URLs, such as:

- www.site.com/index.php?page_path=solutions-overview.html
- www.site.com/index.php?page_path=solutions-a.html

I want to use the RewriteEngine to change the above links to the following respectively:

- www.site.com/solutions/overview
- www.site.com/solutions/a

Below is the .htaccess code I am using:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^solutions/overview index.php?page_path=solutions-overview.html
RewriteRule ^solutions/a index.php?page_path=solutions-a.html
```

This works, however all of my images, CSS files and JS files no longer load because the page is trying to fetch the wrong URLs. For example "/images/blah.jpg" is instead loading as "/solutions/images/blah.jpg".

How can I modify the htaccess code to prevent relative URLs from changing?

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [mod rewrite and static pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250769/mod-rewrite-and-static-pages)

Comment: [Ignacio's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250769/mod-rewrite-and-static-pages/3250856#3250856) in is the general pattern for this...

Comment: Thanks but this didn't help. I cannot find a solution using htaccess. For anyone interested - I solved the issue by adding the following to the header of my HTML `<base href="http://www.site.com/">` so that relative URLs are always resolved from this

Answer (score 4):

Add this line `<BASE href="http://www.yoursitename.com/">` to your page inside the `<head>` tag as follows:

```
<head>
    <title>Your site title</title>
    <BASE href="http://www.yoursitename.com/">
    ....
</head>
```