# ajax files affected by .htaccess

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess

This is my .htaccess file:

```
# Turn rewrite engine on
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

### Rewrite url ###
# Basic rewrite for pages in the admin area
RewriteRule ^admin/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /private/admin/index.php?plugin=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
```

And my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $post = '/private/admin/js/ajax.php';
    $('#email').keyup(function() {
    $.post($post, {email_valid : val}, function(answer) {
                    console.log(answer); // Another pot after this, depending on the answer
   }
});
```

So lets say I'm in domain.com/admin/users/register and I want to check if the email is valid or already used with PHP.

When I have the `$post` like I have above I get the following error: `POST domain/private/admin/js/ajax.php 500 (Internal Server Error)`;

***Update***
Entire 500 error:

```
POST http://domain.com/private/admin/js/ajax.php 500 (Internal Server Error)
n.ajaxTransport.k.cors.a.crossDomain.send @ jquery.js:8630
n.extend.ajax @ jquery.js:8166
n.each.n.(anonymous function) @ jquery.js:8311(anonymous function) @ lr.js:41
n.Callbacks.j @ jquery.js:3099
n.Callbacks.k.fireWith @ jquery.js:3211
x @ jquery.js:8264
n.ajaxTransport.k.cors.a.crossDomain.send.b @ jquery.js:8605
```

`lr.js:41` is where the other post occurs but it is basically the same only the post name is different.

When I change the path to: `/admin/js/ajax.php` I get the error message I made which is: `The plug-in: js and or the page: ajax.php don't exists`. this error message is in the index.php of the admin folder where I include other files. I know the ajax.php file work as I have used it before. And it did work before I used .htaccess file.

File structure:

[image]

I have checked other question before I asked this:

- [.htaccess rewrite without it affecting relative image/css/js URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14269919/htaccess-rewrite-without-it-affecting-relative-image-css-js-urls)
- [mod rewrite and static pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250769/mod-rewrite-and-static-pages)

I hope someone could help me with this problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: What does your error logs say about the 500 error?

Comment: @JonLin updated the error output

Comment: @anubhava I get a blank page also nothing in source

Comment: I meant the apache error logs. On the server's side.

Comment: @JonLin I don't have access to them

Comment: @anubhava in what way should I check the URL in Chrome dev tools?

Comment: Go to Net tab and see what status you get.

Comment: @SuperDJ I bet you have a syntax error or another PHP error. Typically why you get a blank page.  You **have** to have access to error_logs because it can be impossible to troubleshoot without them. Instead of trying to guess. Get your host to provide error logs for you specific site. They can do that.

Comment: So I got access to apache error logs but nothing major or pointing to errors in `lr.js` or `ajax.php`

Comment: @PanamaJack As it is a php file which only shows something when posted to it is no suprise it is blank

Answer (score 1):

Try this .htaccess in `/private/` folder:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /private/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Basic rewrite for pages in the admin area
RewriteRule ^admin/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ admin/index.php?plugin=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Then I guess you don't have any option but to check with your server admins to give you access to Apache error.log

Comment: I got access to apache error log but no errors were found pointing to this problem.

Comment: For any 500 there is always something in Apache error.log